# Exportar pen correctamente a editor de texto

Tags: html, css

Hace unos días estuve modificando un *pen* de un usuario en Codepen.io, cuando lo tuve a mi gusto (en realidad solo lo traduje) lo guardé en mi *dashboard* (Conservé el copyright del creador original).

Ahora lo estoy pasando a mi editor de texto copiando y pegando el contenido de html en codepen a un arhivo `.html` (y así sucesivamente).

Pero cuando abro mi archivo `.html` no me aparecen ciertos estilos CSS como el fondo, y hay una ventana que debería estar oculta ("Registro") y no lo está.

Creo que el error radica en como estoy organizando y llamando las hojas de estilo y el JS.

Les comparto el enlace a Codepen.io [AQUI](https://codepen.io/JheyMejia/pen/vjXREy?editors=1010)

Y así es como lo tengo en mi editor:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".dropdown-button").dropdown();
  $('.modal').modal();
  $(".signup-toggle").click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $(".signupForm").show(300);
    $(".policy").css("visibility", "visible");
  });
});
```

```css
.input-field label {
  color: #999;
}

.input-field input[type=text]:focus+label,
.input-field input[type=password]:focus+label {
  color: #000;
}

.input-field input[type=text]:focus,
.input-field input[type=password]:focus {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #000;
}

.input-field input[type=text].valid,
.input-field input[type=password].valid {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #2196F3;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #2196F3;
}

.input-field input[type=text].invalid,
.input-field input[type=password].invalid {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #F44336;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #F44336;
}

.input-field .prefix.active {
  color: #000;
}


/* Input : switch */

.switch {
  margin-top: 7px;
}

.switch label .lever {
  margin: 0 7px;
}

.switch label input[type="checkbox"]:checked+.lever {
  background-color: #ADD0EB;
}

.switch label input[type="checkbox"]:checked+.lever::after {
  background-color: #4FB0FD;
}

.login-body {
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/5Fx8xis.png');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.input-cart {
  min-height: 400px;
  border-top: 3px solid #2196F3;
  margin-top: 80px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.login {
  margin-top: 25px;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.policy {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.signupForm {
  display: none;
}

.signup {
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.signup-toggle {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 140px;
}

.login h4,
.signup h4 {
  font-weight: 200;
}

.legal {
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.email label {
  margin-left: 11px;
}

.policy {
  font-size: 13px;
}

.main-title {
  font-family: pacifico;
}
```

```html
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <title>Ingreso - ElTarjetero.co</title>

  <!-- favicon -->
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">

  <!-- Custom fonts for this template -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


  <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" rel="stylesheet">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/js/materialize.min.js"></script>


</head>

<body class="login-body">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="input-cart col s12 m10 push-m1 z-depth-2 grey lighten-5">
      <div class="col s12 m5 login">
        <h4 class="center">Ingreso</h4>
        <br>
        <form action="check.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field">
              <input type="text" id="user" name="username" class="validate" required="required" placeholder="Usuario o Correo">
              <label for="user">
                  <i class="material-icons">person</i>                </label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field">
              <input type="password" id="pass" name="password" class="validate" required="required" placeholder="Contraseña">
              <label for="pass">
                <i class="material-icons">lock</i>
                </label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="switch col s6">
              <label>
         <input type="checkbox">
         <span class="lever"></span>
         Recuérdame
        </label>
            </div>
            <div class="col s6">
              <button type="submit" name="login" class="btn waves-effect waves-light blue right">Ingresar</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <!-- Signup form -->
      <div class="col s12 m7 signup">
        <div class="signupForm">
          <h4 class="center">Registro</h4>
          <br>
          <form action="regCheck.php" name="signup" method="post" autocomplete="off">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="input-field col s12 m6">
                <input type="text" id="name-picked" name="namepicked" class="validate" required="required" placeholder="Ingresa un nombre de usuario">
                <label for="name-picked">
                       <i class="material-icons">person_add</i>
                </label>
              </div>
              <div class="input-field col s12 m6">
                <input type="password" id="pass-picked" name="passpicked" class="validate" required="required" placeholder="Contraseña">
                <label for="pass-picked">
                  <i class="material-icons">lock</i>                    </label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="input-field email">
                <div class="col s12">
                  <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="validate" required="required" placeholder="Ingrese su correo">
                  <label for="email">
                    <i class="material-icons">mail</i>
                  </label>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
          <div class="row">
            <button type="submit" name="btn-signup" class="btn blue right waves-effect waves-light">Registrarme</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="signup-toggle center">
          <h4 class="center">No tienes una cuenta? <a href="#!">Regístrate</a></h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col s12">
        <br>
        <div class="legal center">
        </div>
        <div class="legal center">
          <div class="col s12 m7 right">
            <p class="grey-text policy center">Al registrarse, usted acepta nuestra <a href="#!">Política de Privacidad</a> y los <a href="#!">Términos de uso</a>, incluido el <a href="#!">Uso de cookies</a>.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col s12 m5">
            <p class="center grey-text" style="font-size: 14px;">Coding : <a href="http://fb.com/celyes17" class="main-title red-text" target="_blank">Celyes</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="fixed-action-btn toolbar">
    <a class="btn-floating btn-large amber black-text">
    Más
   </a>
    <ul>
      <li><a class="indigo center" href="#!">Facebook Login</a></li>
      <li><a class="blue center" href="#!">Twitter Login</a></li>
      <li><a class="red center" href="#!">Google + Login</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**ACTUALIZACION**

Creo que la falla está en la manera en que inserto en mi html los *"external resources"* 
No sé como debo llamarlos correctamente...

[image: Resources CSS]
[image: Resources JS]

---

Me avergüenzo un poco de mí mismo, pero la solución estaba en una opción (poco visible) en la parte inferior derecha de la página, que da la opción de exportar en .zip, me he descargado el archivo y automáticamente me ha organizado el `.html` llamando el `.css` y el `.js`

:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que en ningún momento mandas a llamar tu JS y tu CSS al HTML, si bien en este sitio o en Codepen.io funcionan correctamente es porque colocas CSS en el área de CSS y JS en su respetiva área por eso no es necesario llamarlo. ahora lo que necesitas hacer para que funcione es crear un archivo CSS y colocar todo esto:

```
.input-field label {
  color: #999;
}

.input-field input[type=text]:focus+label, .input-field input[type=password]:focus+label {
  color: #000;
}

...

.main-title {
  font-family: pacifico;
}
```

y lo mismo tendras que hacerlo para JS, crear un archivo .js y copiar todo esto:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".dropdown-button").dropdown();
  $('.modal').modal();
  $(".signup-toggle").click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $(".signupForm").show(300);
    $(".policy").css("visibility", "visible");
  });
});
```

y finalmente llamar estos archivos en tu HTML

ejemplo :
Suponiendo que tus archivos están en el mismo directorio que tu HTML este seria tu HTML finalmente.

```
    <html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>Ingreso - ElTarjetero.co</title>

    <!-- favicon -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">

    <!-- Custom fonts for this template --> 
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">    
</head>

<body class="login-body">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-cart col s12 m10 push-m1 z-depth-2 grey lighten-5">
            <div class="col s12 m5 login">
                <h4 class="center">Ingreso</h4>
                <br>
                <form action="check.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="input-field">
                            <input type="text" id="user" name="username" class="validate" required="required" placeholder="Usuario o Correo">
                            <label for="user">
                  <i class="material-icons">person</i>                </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="input-field">
                            <input type="password" id="pass" name="password" class="validate" required="required" placeholder="Contraseña">
                            <label for="pass">
                <i class="material-icons">lock</i>
                </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="switch col s6">
                            <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox">
                                    <span class="lever"></span>
                                    Recuérdame
                                </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col s6">
                            <button type="submit" name="login" class="btn waves-effect waves-light blue right">Ingresar</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <!-- Signup form -->
            <div class="col s12 m7 signup">
                <div class="signupForm">
                    <h4 class="center">Registro</h4>
                    <br>
                    <form action="regCheck.php" name="signup" method="post" autocomplete="off">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="input-field col s12 m6">
                                <input type="text" id="name-picked" name="namepicked" class="validate" required="required" placeholder="Ingresa un nombre de usuario">
                                <label for="name-picked">
                       <i class="material-icons">person_add</i>
                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="input-field col s12 m6">
                                <input type="password" id="pass-picked" name="passpicked" class="validate" required="required" placeholder="Contraseña">
                                <label for="pass-picked">
                  <i class="material-icons">lock</i>                    </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="input-field email">
                                <div class="col s12">
                                    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="validate" required="required" placeholder="Ingrese su correo">
                                    <label for="email">
                    <i class="material-icons">mail</i>
                  </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <div class="row">
                        <button type="submit" name="btn-signup" class="btn blue right waves-effect waves-light">Registrarme</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="signup-toggle center">
                    <h4 class="center">No tienes una cuenta? <a href="#!">Regístrate</a></h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col s12">
                <br>
                <div class="legal center">
                </div>
                <div class="legal center">
                    <div class="col s12 m7 right">
                        <p class="grey-text policy center">Al registrarse, usted acepta nuestra <a href="#!">Política de Privacidad</a> y los <a href="#!">Términos de uso</a>, incluido el <a href="#!">Uso de cookies</a>.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col s12 m5">
                        <p class="center grey-text" style="font-size: 14px;">Coding : <a href="http://fb.com/celyes17" class="main-title red-text" target="_blank">Celyes</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="fixed-action-btn toolbar">
        <a class="btn-floating btn-large amber black-text">
                Más
            </a>
        <ul>
            <li><a class="indigo center" href="#!">Facebook Login</a></li>
            <li><a class="blue center" href="#!">Twitter Login</a></li>
            <li><a class="red center" href="#!">Google + Login</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Finalmete como observación:

Los CSS se mandan a llamar con

```
<link href="directorio de css">
```

y los JS con

```
<script src="directorio js"></script>
```

Comment: Te agradezco que te hayas tomado tu tiempo. Efectivamente tengo en mi equipo los tres archivos que copié de codepen: index.html - style.css - index.js Hice lo que tu me dijiste llamando la hoja de estilos y el JS desde mi index.html pero sigo con el mismo error

Comment: los 3 archivos están en la misma carpeta? , podrías indicar como lo estas llamando?

Comment: Un detalle que veo que tienes es que estas llamando archivos js con **<link>** y debería ser con la etiqueta **<script>**

Comment: Hola @Silvestre Acabo de editar mi pregunta con las correciones que me sugeriste, la ventana "registrate" sigue sin poder desplegarse despúes de clicarla. Y algunas letras estan montadas sobre iconos

Comment: He editado la respuesta poniendo como debe quedar tu HTML al final, lo he probado y sin ningún problema me corre, solucionando lo de tus iconos y también despliega la pantalla de **Registro**